# keycloak store token in cookie instead of header

Tags: cookies, token, keycloak

I'm working with a REST API and Keycloak.
I am saving the token in cookie instead of the header so that all the requests that the browser performs carry the token (browser application).

On the server I am using the spring security adapter (config xml) How do I modify it to find the token in the cookie instead of the header of the request?

Comment: The Spring Security Adapter already uses the JSESSION ID, which is mapped with an access token in the server. The JSESSION ID is stored as a cookie in the browser during your whole session. What's your concrete question?